# Deserialize XML string into c# object result in nullable data

Tags: .net, .net-core, xmlserializer

Deserializng XML string into c# object doesnt work, as I'm still getting nullable values.  `Errors`, `RequestStatus` and `Version` are all showing null values.

Need an eagle eye here to see what am I misunderstanding.  I'm not new to Dot Net framework but I'm new to Dot Net Core, so maybe something different there I don't know about.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", ElementName = "Root", DataType = "string", IsNullable = true)]
public class GetAuthorizationTokenResponse
{
    public class RootDetail
    {
        public class RequestHeadDetail
        {
            [XmlElement("Errors")]
            public string Errors { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("RequestStatus")]
            public string RequestStatus { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("Version")]
            public string Version { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlElement("RequestHead")]
        public RequestHeadDetail RequestHead { get; set; } = new RequestHeadDetail();
    }

    [XmlElement("Root")]
    public RootDetail Root { get; set; } = new RootDetail();
}

var xmlResult = "<Root><RequestHead><Errors/><RequestStatus>0</RequestStatus><Version>2.3.2</Version></RequestHead></Root>";
var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlResult);
var test = (Ituran.GetAuthorizationTokenResponse)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class structure corresponds to:

```
<Root>
    <Root>
    …
    </Root>
</Root>
```

The first `<Root>` element corresponds to `GetAuthorizationTokenResponse` class, and the second one to `RootDetail` class. Either remove one of these, or restructure your input XML.

Comment: Seems that getting rid of `public RootDetail Root {get;set;]` will have to make do with.  That works now.  :-/  Gonna be tough to make this work with JSON and XML back 'n forth.  :-/